# How can you load binary data into Spark where the position/offset of data is important?

Tags: pyspark

I need to load data that is split into two parts:

- A file describing a binary file e.g. the binary file contains X groups, each containing Y values with certain metadata.
- A (large) binary file containing X * Y values, corresponding to the order in the definition file.

The output would be:
(X, Y, value) for all X and Y in each pair of files.

One solution is to load everything via Python, using `rdd.flatmap()` to yield data row by row:

```py
def load_definition_and_binary_file(file_path):
   x_list, y_list = load_definition_file(...)

   with open(binary_file) as b_fo:f
       for x in x_list:
           raw_data = b_fo.read(len(y_list) * DATA_SIZE)
           decoded_values = struct.unpack_from(DATA_FORMAT, raw_data)

           for (y, value) in zip(y_list, decoded_values):
               yield (x, y, value)

file_paths_df.rdd.flatmap(load_definition_and_binary_file).toDF()
```

This works, but seems to be slow, and Spark is outputting results in massive partitions rather than breaking things up into chunks.

As far as I can tell, the built-in Spark data loading does not support preserving offsets or line numbers from files, so it's not possible to load the definition and binary files individually, and then join them later.

I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways to load the data e.g. using pandas/pyarrow, or with built-in data loading like `SparkContext.binaryRecords()`.